# How to prevent page-break for table's header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to apply page break to all rows in table, except for those in header. 
I use this code in my style sheet:

```
@media print {
    th, thead {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        page-break-after: avoid !important;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Please guide me

Comment: Did you try to add `page-break-before: auto !important;`?

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: thanks but dose't work again @Ahmad

Comment: then maybe it is un-`avoid`able  in your case.

Comment: when apply table { page-break-inside: avoid !important;} will work @Ahmad

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#search=page-break-inside e.g. 'avoid' in case of 'page-break-after' is not working in most cases.